# Dojo editor bold icon not working in IE11

Tags: dojo

We are using the `dojo.editor` class to get the rich text wordpad. But when select the text and then click either the bold, italic, underline or strike-through formatting options.  Neither changes the highlighted text.  The text is no longer highlighted and the cursor goes to the beginning of the text.

Shortcut keys are working though (CTRL+B for bold, CTRL+I for italic and CTRL+U for underlined.  I don’t believe there is a standard shortcut key for strike-through)

The problem only appears in IE11, other browsers and all working fine.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?  It's possible you're using a version prior to IE11 fixes being applied.  For example, this problem exists in 1.9.1 but not 1.9.2+.

Comment: Hi , I am using dojo 1.5 version and issue exists in IE 11.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the last backports 1.5 got were for IE9 (in 1.5.2).  It never received backports of the IE11 fixes, and there were a bunch of them for Editor for the 1.8 branch and up (1.8.6, 1.9.2, and 1.10.x don't have this issue).I would stronly advise upgrading, since the likelihood of backports to 1.5 seems unlikely given the effort that would likely be involved to try to resolve merge conflicts (and given that 1.5 itself is almost 5 years old now).

Answer (score 3):

You are encountering an issue which was fixed in Dojo 1.8.6, 1.9.2, and 1.10.0 due to a series of IE11-related fixes (mostly due to UA sniffing code needing to be updated).

Given that you're using 1.5, which was first released in July 2010 and last received backports for IE9, the likelihood of a backport of IE11 fixes to 1.5 at this point is slim to none (barring [commercial support](http://www.sitepen.com/support), at least), given the effort it would likely involve to backport all relevant fixes and resolve merge conflicts in the process.

I would strongly advise upgrading to the latest version of Dojo 1.8, 1.9, or 1.10.  [Release Notes](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/releasenotes/) are available for each minor version along the way.